# Build class library doesnt update reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019 CE with all updates as of today.

1. I create a Blank Solution.
2. Add Empty web project to the blank solution.
3. Add a class library.
4. Reference the library in my web project.

I build the **Solution** and can tell the library is working as intended.

I make a small change to the class library and build the **Class Library only**. The change i made doesnt reflect the output im expecting. If i rebuild the entire solution then the change i made does take affect.

Normally i can just build the single library and that does the trick. I cant work out why the entire solution needs to be built in order for the changes to come across to the web project? I even deleted the CL and added a new one but the same occurs - am i missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: In order for your web application to use the new version of the dll it needs to have a *copy* of that dll. That's one of the steps the build step is performing, gathering all the required files necessary to run the web application. Since you skip this, the web application still has the old copy.

Comment: When you build your webapp, all referenced libraries are built, too and an assembly is copied over to the debug /output folder of your webapp. When you only build the library, it will not put an updated assembly into the output folder of your web application.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Normally i can just build the single library and that does the trick"? If you configure the class library project to place the compiled output into a different folder, one that is being used by the web application, that would work, but that's not the default behavior.

Comment: By that i mean, i just build the class library and the web project references the latest change. Currently when i build (the class library), it doesnt. Only when i rebuild the solution it does which i didnt want to do

Comment: @Computer, based on my test, the code will change if I only build the class lib only. Do you reference that project or only the dll?